# How do I search and iterate this object for an id?

Tags: javascript

I have an object where the values are arrays and they've further objects inside them like this:

```
let primaryStandard = {
  section1: [{name: 'andy', id: 1}, {name: 'charles', id: 2},...],
  section2: [{name: 'megan', id: 55}, {name: 'derek', id: 56},...],
  section3: [{name: 'robert', id: 95}, {name: 'nathan', id: 96},...],
}
```

Basically, I want to iterate this whole object for a particular `id` value and then get the `name` and `section` in an object.

**Example:**

For `id = 95` the result should be `` {section: section3, name: 'robert`} ``

**What I've tried so far:**

```js
let primaryStandard = {
  section1: [{name: 'andy', id: 1}, {name: 'charles', id: 2}],
  section2: [{name: 'megan', id: 55}, {name: 'derek', id: 56}],
  section3: [{name: 'robert', id: 95}, {name: 'nathan', id: 96}],
}

for (let key of Object.keys(primaryStandard)) {
      console.log((primaryStandard[key])) // logs the values(array)
      primaryStandard[key].map(student => console.log(student)) // .map() is not defined error
}
```

Comment: **class** is a javascript keyword, rename your variable

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score -1):

You could do this using `find` method on `Object.keys` to get section and name.

```js
let data = {section1: [{name: 'andy', id: 1}, {name: 'charles', id: 2}],section2: [{name: 'megan', id: 55}, {name: 'derek', id: 56}],section3: [{name: 'robert', id: 95}, {name: 'nathan', id: 96}],}

let name;
let section = Object.keys(data).find(key => {
  const match = data[key].find(({id}) => id == 95);
  if(match) return name = match.name
})

console.log({name, section})
```